# How to pass arguments to a "sub class" in coffeescript

Tags: javascript, iterator, coffeescript

I have the following code which defines an Iterator prototype in coffeescript ( extending the Array prototype ) :

```
App.Utils.Iterator = do ->
  Iterator =  ->
    Array.apply(this,arguments)
    ### this.push(i) for i in arguments : works but not good practice
    iter = 0
    @reset = ->
      iter = 0
    @getIndex = ->
      iter
    @getValue= ->
      this[iter]
    @next= ->
      this[++iter] if iter < this.length-1
    @previous= ->
      this[--iter] if iter>0
    @hasNext= ->
      return if this[iter+1] then true else return false
    @hasPrevious= ->
      return  if this[iter-1]then true else return false
    return this

  Iterator.prototype = new Array()
  Iterator.prototype.constructor = Array
  return Iterator
```

Everything works fine however i want to instanciate the iterator like an Array :

```
iterator = new App.Utils.Iterator(1,2,3,4)
```

which returns [] on the console

how to make it initialize my iterator like a regular array  ( new Array(1,2,3,4) returns [1,2,3,4] ) without pushing the arguments in the constructor function ( the instruction has been commented in my code )

thanks

Comment: I'm still trying to understand this code. I can't help yet, but do you intend to re-define all of your prototype methods every time the constructor is called? That looks like what is happening. Ah, I see, you do that so you can have a closure around `iter`.

Comment: @Hemlock : yes,  I want iter to be "private" , that's why i do that.

Answer (score -1):

There are several design mistakes in your code because of which the entity you're trying to create is anything but an Iterator. Iterator is something you use to iterate over an existing array or other iterable data type - it is not the iterable itself. That's why:

1. a reasonable parameter to your constructor is an array (`new Iterator [1,2,3,4]`)
2. `Iterator` should not extend `Array`
3. instead of resetting iterator just create a new instance of it for every iteration

Now to your question.

Firstly, without recreating a bunch of Javascript boilerplate your code could be rewritten as:

```
class Iterator extends Array
  constructor: ->
    iter = 0
    @reset = ->
      iter = 0
    @getIndex = ->
      iter
    @getValue = ->
      @[iter]
    @next = ->
      @[++iter] if iter < @length-1
    @previous = ->
      @[--iter] if iter > 0
    @hasNext = ->
      if @[iter+1] then true else false
    @hasPrevious = ->
      if @[iter-1] then true else false
    super
```

Secondly, why overcomplicate things like that and introduce overhead just for the sake of "hiding" one variable in a dynamic imperative language? The code must be rewritten in the following form:

```
class Iterator extends Array
  constructor: ->
    @iter = 0
    super
  reset: ->
    @iter = 0
  getIndex: ->
    @[@iter]
  # ...
```

Thirdly, it is impossible to pass a list of parameters to an extended array. Probably it is a `[]` sugar-related javascript issue. The proposed by you pushing the arguments in the constructor solution is fine. Considering all the other mistakes you'll make if you'll still stick to writing such a class I don't think that question of good practice should bother you anyway.

P.S. Why anybody would need an iterator in Coffeescript is a question. I think you should better read some book about Coffeescript before diving into programming a library which you won't use. Try [this one](http://arcturo.github.com/library/coffeescript/index.html).

Comment: I need to create a undo - redo capability in my program. and that solution works quite well.

Comment: @camus Firstly, if you wanna play a smart S, your question makes no sense: you can't pass arguments to a subclass, to pass it to a super you do that with the `super` statement as it is described in the answer. Secondly, if you read it the answer is neither about implementing Iterator. Thirdly, use your class for whatever purposes you want, but naming it Iterator is a mistake for reasons already explained.

Comment: @Volkov , your comment doesnt make sense ,i'm asking a question , not playing smart. and part of the answer you provided had nothing to do the question. We are not here to debate wether naming a class Iterator is good , i could have named my class foo , nobody gives a damn .but how to pass arguments to the constructor of a super class and apply it to the child class using a closure, Capice ?